# numpy sum of fixed columns in a given row

Tags: python, numpy

Say, I have a numpy array like this:

```
[[ 1 2 3 5]
 [ 4 5 6 8]
 [ 7 8 9 11]]
```

I want to get the sum of (col 0+col 2) and (col1+col3) for each row.
I know its probably elementary, but cant get it. Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes it's pretty elementary once you know the assignment scheme of numpy arrays :

Let

```
    x = [[ 1 2 3 5]
         [ 4 5 6 8]
         [ 7 8 9 11]]

y1 = x[:,0]+x[:,2]    # Sum of columns 0 and 2
y1 = array([4,10,16])
y2 = x[:,1]+x[:,3]    # Sum of columns 1 and 3
y2 = array([7,13,19])
```

Comment: So what if I have 1000 columns? Should we write 2000 lines of code for that?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
mat=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
A=np.sum(mat,axis=0)[0::2] 
B=np.sum(mat,axis=0)[1::2]
```

A = (col 0+col 2)
B = (col1 + col3)

Comment: Note, that I used the variable mat, which is different from your matrix. Just substitute mat in line 3 and 4 with the variable of your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
Out[99]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

**Solution**

```
#reshape the array to 2 columns, then sum columns, finally reshape it back to 2 columns.
a.reshape(-1,2).sum(1).reshape(-1,2)
Out[102]: 
array([[ 1,  5],
       [ 9, 13],
       [17, 21]])
```